# Histogram update in a for loop with matplotlib.pylab

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

I am trying to update in for loop a histogram data. but I don't know how to make it.
I tried with set_data but it is not working.
here is the code:

```
plt.ion()
ax=plt.subplot(111)
[n,X, V]=ax.hist(range(MAX_X),bins=33,normed=True)

....

alternative=defaultdict(list)
...



for z in range(0,max(alternative)):
stat=zeros(33,int)
for i in range(len(alternative[z])):
    stat[alternative[z][i]]+=1

[n,X, V].set_data(stat)// problem here!!!!!!!
plt.draw()
```

Comment: `[n,X,V]` is a list, it does not have a `set_data` method.

Comment: thanks @ebarr for your answer. how can I then update the data in a for loop?

Comment: you can just delete the patches and call hist again; ax.patches = [] ; ax.hist(  ... )

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So the problem comes from the fact that `[n,X,V]` is a list with no `set_data` method. As far as I am aware, there is no easy way to "update" a histogram in the way you describe without manually reordering and organising the underlying `Patches` objects.

You would be just as well clearing the axis are replotting each time:

This:

```
[n,X, V].set_data(stat)// problem here!!!!!!!
plt.draw()
```

becomes:

```
ax.cla()
[n,X, V]=ax.hist(stat,bins=33,normed=True)
plt.draw()
```

Assuming that `stat` is an array that you want to histogram.