# General way to animate any artist in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation

I have tried to animate two different artists `plt.quiver()` and `plt.hist()` in matplotlib recently and both times I ran into the same problem. Apparently those classes (I hope my OOP literacy is holding up) both don't have a `set_data` like method. Well, technically `plt.quiver()` does have `set_UVC`, but that doesn't work with `Line3D` instances, only with `Line2D`. Also, there is an example for [animating a histogram](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/animation/animated_histogram.html), but it seemed like some serious jerry-rigging to me. I tried to simply define my artist with new values in the `update()` function and then just return the new artist instead of defining the artist *outside* the `update()` and then updating the data of the artist using a `set_data()` method. But this only results in an animation in which all frames are kept in the plot and overlap. Below are the animations for both the Histogram and the Quiver plot.

Histogram:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation

"""
evolution of mean values produced by 1000 dice rolls with 
more and more dices, which lead to a narrowing variance
with a growing number of dices.
"""

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

def update(i):

    k = [np.mean(np.random.randint(0,7,i)) for j in range(1000)]
    lol = ax.hist(k,bins=20)

    return lol

ani = FuncAnimation(fig, update, frames=(1,2,10,100,1000))

plt.show()
```

Quiver:

```py
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation

def rot_z(angle):

    o   = 2*np.pi*(angle/360)

    mat = np.array(((np.cos(o),-np.sin(o),0),
                    (np.sin(o), np.cos(o),0),
                    (    0    ,     0    ,0)))

    return mat

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

ax.set_xlim(-1.5,1.5)
ax.set_ylim(-1.5,1.5)
ax.set_zlim(-1.5,1.5)

def update(frame):

    x,y,z = rot_z(frame).dot(np.array((1,1,1)))

    quiv = ax.quiver(0,
              0, 
              0, 
              x, 
              y, 
              z, 
              length=1)

    return quiv

ani = FuncAnimation(fig, update, frames=np.linspace(0,360,100))
plt.show()
```

If you run them, you can see the issue. So I wanted to know: Isn't there an easier, abstractable way of animating artists, or am I at the mercy of potentially non-existent setters? I have checked both `dir(plt.quiver), dir(plt.hist)` to see if I was simply overlooking those methods in the docs, but the example of the animated histogram seemed to confirm my fears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to clear the image at every update with `ax.clear()`. Maybe the histogram animation would be more smooth if you would extend an array of throws instead of restarting from scratch at each frame?

**Edit**: the code below includes a test to reuse the same samples

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
randnums = [np.random.randint(0,7,1000) for j in range(1000)]

def update(i):

    k = [np.mean(randnums[j][:i]) for j in range(1000)]
    ax.clear()
    lol = ax.hist(k,bins=20)

    return lol

ani = FuncAnimation(fig, update, frames=[2**t for t in range(11)])

plt.show()
```

Comment: Yeah I don't really need high preformance right now so this works, but I understand that using setters is the whole point to achieve better preformance. Extending an array? I'm not really getting you there. The throws are supposed to be independent of one another.

Comment: Oh so you just made an load of values beforehand and then just slice for them. Yeah that makes sense, thanks very much.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23247154/histogram-update-in-a-for-loop-with-matplotlib-pylab about updating histograms

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19329039/plotting-animated-quivers-in-python about updating Quiver vectors

Comment: If this answer was helpful, you might consider upvoting.